# Another JPA Question

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, java-ee-5

I have this code:

```
@PersistenceContext(name="persistence/monkey", unitName="deltaflow-pu")
...
@Stateless
public class GahBean implements GahRemote {
```

But when I use this:

```
try{
 InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
 System.out.println("Pissing me off * " + ic.lookup("java:comp/env/persistent/monkey"));
 Iterator e = ic.getEnvironment().values().iterator();
 while ( e.hasNext() )
     System.out.println("rem - " + e.next());
}catch(Exception a){ a.printStackTrace();}
```

I get this exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/persistent/monkey
```

If I remove the lookup the iterator doesn't have anything close to it either.  What could be the problem?

Comment: I would recommend you edit your question: "Another JPA Question *rolls eyes*" does nothing to describe the problem other than indicating it involves JPA and notes your frustration.  Perhaps include something about exception in title.

Comment: I took off the rolls eyes for him.

Answer (score 1):

This could be my ignorance about JPA showing, but you appear to have "persistence" in some places and "persistent" in others.  I'd start by making sure the names match.

Answer (score 0):

If I inject it by the way it works fine, but everywhere I read about that they say it isn't threadsafe to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have configured the data source on the server with the name persistence/monkey and check whether the name is matched in persistance.xml
The name is case sensitive.